# import from another folder python 3 (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python-3.x, import

My `main.py` script is in directory:

```
/Documents/scriptie/anaconda3/
```

In this script, I want to import the file `'process.py'`, which is in directory: /Documents/scriptie/anaconda3/ui

(in both directories there is a `__init__.py` file)

I have tried several things in the main.py script:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/Documents/scriptie/anaconda3/ui') 
#also tried sys.path.append
import process
```

this gave the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'process'

```
from .Documents.scriptie.anaconda3.ui.process import ProcessTab 
'''
ProcessTab is a class in process.py. tried it with and 
without the dot '.' in front of Documents 
'''
```

This gave the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError:
No module named '__main__.Documents'; '__main__' is not a package
```

When I tried the following code:

```
from .ui import process
```

this gave the error:

```
 No module named '__main__.ui'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I can't figure out another option, so I hope someone can help me solve this error!

I am using python 3 on an OSX.

Comment: When i try to do it like this: from ui.process import ProcessTab, i get an error 'abort trap: 6'

Comment: I found the cause of the error!! In one of the other imported files I used **import matplotlib.pyplot as plt**. I changed this into: **from sys import platform as sys_pf
if sys_pf == 'darwin':
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use("TkAgg")** and now it works :)